# Choose citation style when using child documents

Tags: lyx, citing, thesis, elsarticle

I am writing my thesis in Lyx, and have used the "thesis" template with have several child documents. My referencing style is "elsarticle-harv". My problem is that I can not choose the citation style when writing in the child documents. They all appear like this: Name (year).

I want to able to choose where the parentheses show up, e.g:

If I write a statement from a book, I want the reference to show up in parentheses in the end (Name, year). 
Or if I writhe "according to Name (year) the blabla..."

When inserting citation in the child document my only option for citation style is [#ID].

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is:
The options of citation styles you are given depend on the citestyle you have choosen in the (child) document settings. I guess you have choosen standard here instead of natbib or jurabib. I don't know whether there is a way to automatically sync the document settings of the master and child document, so check in both documents settings!